# Ubuntu sometimes immediately shuts down when power button is pressed (but only sometimes)

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, hibernate

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on my Lenovo Y500 laptop, and I'm getting strange behavior surrounding the power button. The series of events goes something like this:

1. I turn on my computer and enter Ubuntu (I am dual-booting with Windows 8.1 using rEFInd, by the way)
2. I press the power button on my laptop, which brings up a small gui menu on Ubuntu, allowing me to choose from several shut-down-related options. I hibernate the computer, using the gui.
3. I turn my computer back on and re-enter Ubuntu.
4. I press the power button. The gui menu from before briefly flashes before the computer abruptly enters a shutdown sequence without any further action on my part. It's as if it immediately assumed I had clicked on the option for 'shutdown'.

This exact series is basically how it goes every time; that is, Ubuntu will display me the menu if I'm running from a cold boot, but not if I restarted from a hibernation. How can I get this gui to come up (and stay up without it choosing for me) every time?

Additional information: I get an apport error message dialog that shows up every time I reboot after the computer immediately turning itself off.

Comment: I've got the exactly same problem with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Dell M4600 laptop. The problem happens with kernel 3.13, 3.14 and even 3.16. I don't use hibernate to disk very often, but I use suspend quite a lot, and typically one in 10 suspends fails - i.e. goes straight to shutdown instead of displaying the menu. Also, sometimes there are still (fortunately) rare problems with NVidia graphics not waking up properly after suspend.

Comment: Have you tried this solution to modify logind.conf: http://askubuntu.com/questions/451009/xubuntu-14-04-power-button-instantly-powers-off-laptop-instead-of-showing-shutdo